# Get audio input channel from mixer NAudio C#

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, asio

I am very New to `NAudio` Library and as well as develop audio type of file I have question that how do we get audio input from each channel of Mixer use USB Audio Interface connect to PC (Support ASIO), So this mixer support 8 Channel of Audio Input.

> The idea of application is like this
>
> - when user press on channel 1 button it will get channel 1 input to capture the voice of speaker on that particular channel
> - when user press channel 2 button it will get voice from channel 2 (as separate Channel)

So I just wondering which library class I should use and is there any source code example or best practice for this kind of scenario (I am using C# to Develop)

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace NaudioAsioTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitialiseAsioControls();
        }

    private void InitialiseAsioControls()
    {
        // Just fill the comboBox AsioDriver with available driver names
        var asioDriverNames = AsioOut.GetDriverNames();
        foreach (string driverName in asioDriverNames)
        {
            comboBoxAsioDriver.Items.Add(driverName);
        }
        //comboBoxAsioDriver.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    public string SelectedDeviceName { get { return (string)comboBoxAsioDriver.SelectedItem; } }

    private void OnButtonControlPanelClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var asio = new AsioOut(SelectedDeviceName))
            {
                asio.ShowControlPanel();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void comboBoxAsioDriver_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var asio = new AsioOut(SelectedDeviceName))
            {
                //asio.ShowControlPanel();
                int nrOfChannelOUTDevices = asio.DriverOutputChannelCount;
                int nrOfChannelINDevices = asio.DriverInputChannelCount;
                listBoxInputs.Items.Clear();
                listBoxOutputs.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < nrOfChannelOUTDevices; i++)
                {
                    string name = asio.AsioInputChannelName(i);
                    listBoxInputs.Items.Add(name);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < nrOfChannelINDevices; i++)
                {
                    string name = asio.AsioOutputChannelName(i);
                    listBoxOutputs.Items.Add(name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


}
```

}

The result is the following:

[image]